# conflicting scripts not functioning

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have using 2 scripts declared on my footer. each script works perfectly when declared alone but if I declared the second one. the other function the other not.

Here is the code that works when declared alone and with the other script.
This has his own js file.

```
var fixed = false;

$(document).scroll(function() {
    if( $(this).scrollTop() > 20 ) {
        if( !fixed ) {
            fixed = true;
            $('.navbar-fixed-top').addClass('scroll');

        }
    } else {
        if( fixed ) {
            fixed = false;
            $('.navbar-fixed-top').removeClass('scroll');

        }
    }
});

/*
 * Smooth Scroll
 */


$(function() {

        function filterPath(string) {
            return string
            .replace(/^\//,'')
            .replace(/(index|default).[a-zA-Z]{3,4}$/,'')
            .replace(/\/$/,'');
        }

        var locationPath = filterPath(location.pathname);
        var scrollElem = scrollableElement('html', 'body');

        // Any links with hash tags in them (can't do ^= because of fully qualified URL potential)
        $('a[href*=#]').each(function() {

            // Ensure it's a same-page link
            var thisPath = filterPath(this.pathname) || locationPath;
            if (  locationPath == thisPath
                && (location.hostname == this.hostname || !this.hostname)
                && this.hash.replace(/#/,'') ) {

                    // Ensure target exists
                    var $target = $(this.hash), target = this.hash;
                    if (target) {

                        // Find location of target
                        var targetOffset = $target.offset().top;
                        $(this).click(function(event) {

                            // Prevent jump-down
                            event.preventDefault();

                            // Animate to target
                            $(scrollElem).animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, 400, function() {

                                // Set hash in URL after animation successful
                                location.hash = target;

                            });
                        });
                    }
            }

        });

        // Use the first element that is "scrollable"  (cross-browser fix?)
        function scrollableElement(els) {
            for (var i = 0, argLength = arguments.length; i <argLength; i++) {
                var el = arguments[i],
                $scrollElement = $(el);
                if ($scrollElement.scrollTop()> 0) {
                    return el;
                } else {
                    $scrollElement.scrollTop(1);
                    var isScrollable = $scrollElement.scrollTop()> 0;
                    $scrollElement.scrollTop(0);
                    if (isScrollable) {
                        return el;
                    }
                }
            }
            return [];
        }

    });
```

The other one is this declared below the first script. now this didn't work when the other is present but works perfectly when alone. also I tried the no conflicting script but same goes for the result.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$(function(){
   document.querySelector( "#nav-toggle" )
    .addEventListener( "click", function() {
      this.classList.toggle( "active" );
      $(".navmobile").slideToggle();
 });
});
      $(window).resize(function() {
      if ($(window).width() >= 767) {
         $(".navmobile").hide();
      }
      else {
    $("#nav-toggle").removeClass("active");
    $(".navmobile").hide();
    }
   });
});
</script>
```

Comment: *"the other function the other not."* I have no idea what that means.

Comment: the script doesn't work together. 1 work while the other not. only 1 function is working when both are declared.

Comment: So you need to figure out why. Seems like both are working on anchors so I am guessing you need to exclude the anchor that the one is using from being selected by the other.

Comment: i got and internal server error on my favicon.ico when i click on the nav toggle function. basically it should just add a class on the anchor. dont know why it the console is giving an error on the favico

Answer (score 0):

You probably have this element in your code:

```
<a href="#" id="nav-toggle"></a>
```

Note the `href="#"` part - the first script is using `event.preventDefault()` for every A element with href that containing "#", so the second script doesn't get click event. **remove the `href="#"`** from that element (or leave the attribute empty) and it should work.

Comment: yes I have that code. `<a id="nav-toggle" href="#"><span></span></a>` but removing the href doesn't fix anything

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
// Any links with hash tags in them (can't do ^= because of fully qualified URL potential)
$('a[href*=#]').each(function() {
```

to

```
// Any links with hash tags in them (can't do ^= because of fully qualified URL potential)
$('a[href*=#]').not("#av-toggle").each(function() {
```

so the first script ignore the link you are clicking to do the toggling.